# see nginx logs in linuxserver/letsencrypt docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have built and run a docker image from **`linuxserver/letsencrypt`**, I volumed my own nginx configurations in `/config/nginx/site-confs/default` and it is working properly with my nginx config.

Now I want to see nginx logs but `/var/logs/nginx/access.log` is empty,
`/var/log/nginx/error.log` only contains this line:

```
[emerg] 479#479: open() "/run/nginx/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I don't know if this error is causing anything because nginx is still working properly.

Also, when I run `docker logs -f docker_image_name` I get letsencrypt logs and not nginx logs, which contains some lines related to the very first moment that everything is configured fine and certificate is created.

I want to see logs from requests that come to nginx on this docker but I don't know if they exist anywhere and if they do, where to find them.

Comment: Can you check where nginx write the  logs? If you can see them in stdout of the docker, maybe is because nginx itself sends them there (Like error_log /dev/stdout info; access_log /dev/stdout info; . Mind that all those logs will be erased if you take down the docker and up it. (also, change those values for the log file where you want to write them).

Comment: @flaixman The problem is I don't know where the logs are written, maybe I need to read the source code of the linuxserver/letsencrypt to see how it is configuring nginx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up reading the source code and searching about the solution afterwards,

[Here](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-letsencrypt/blob/7fc0d59afd8324edfed9412d30dad0b92c28bddb/root/defaults/nginx.conf#L40) is the part in [linuxserver/letsencrypt](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-letsencrypt) repo that default nginx configuration says nginx logs are saved in `/config/log/nginx/`.
So I added these two lines in my own nginx config to get nginx logs with docker logs:

```
access_log /dev/stdout;
error_log /dev/stdout;
```

Comment: Glad you found it!

Comment: Glad you posted an answer! :)